# plot within a plot: zoom into a plot so that the magnified part is framed by axis with ticks and tick labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to zoom into a plot much like it is possible by using the `spy` library but I want the spy-in node to contain its own ticks and tick labels with a finer grid than the original plot. To clarify what I mean I prepared the following picture by editing a picture that was produced with `pgfplots` and the `spy` library with the program Inkscape:

[image]

Here is the code for the "`pgfplots` and `spy`"-part of the picture:

```
\documentclass{standalone}   

\usepackage{pgfplots}   
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\usetikzlibrary{spy,backgrounds}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread{
0.0    1.0
0.0   -0.5
}\datatable

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [spy using outlines={rectangle, magnification=2, size=0.5cm, connect spies}]
\begin{axis}[
  xlabel={Energy},
  ylabel={Intensity},
  x unit={eV}
]
\addplot +[mark=none] table [x index=0, y index=1] {\datatable};
\addplot +[mark=none] {0.1*x^2};

\begin{scope}
    \spy[black,size=2cm] on (4.25,1.65) in node [fill=none] at (5,5.5);
\end{scope}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I'm not sure whether this is possible using the `spy` library or not. Maybe another approach is needed to achieve this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need another approach to achieve the effect since a spy glass will never generate its own `pgfplots` axis (it operates on a lower left of `pgf`).

A possible solution would be to create a separate `pgfplots` axis into some node (perhaps a `pin`) and reconfigure the separate axis accordingly:

```
\documentclass{article}   

\usepackage{pgfplots}   
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\usetikzlibrary{spy,backgrounds}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread{
0.0    1.0
0.0   -0.5
}\datatable

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every pin/.style={fill=white}]
\begin{axis}[
  xlabel={Energy},
  ylabel={Intensity},
  x unit={eV}
]
\addplot +[mark=none] table [x index=0, y index=1] {\datatable};
\addplot +[mark=none] {0.1*x^2};

\coordinate (pt) at (axis cs:0,0);
\end{axis}

\node[pin=70:{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,trim axis left,trim axis right]
    \begin{axis}[
        tiny,
      xlabel={Energy},
      ylabel={Intensity},
      x unit={eV},
      xmin=-1,xmax=1,
      ymin=-0.2,ymax=0.2,
      enlargelimits,
    ]
    \addplot +[mark=none] table [x index=0, y index=1] {\datatable};
    \addplot +[mark=none] {0.1*x^2};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}] at (pt) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This generates a separate axis inside of a pin argument. In order to reduce the bounding box (and therefore the target location of the pin), I chose to trim the axis on the left and on the right. The `every pin` option of the outer picture configures a fill color for the nested pin. Note that `pgfplots` does not support nested axes which is why I moved the pin after `\end{axis}` of the first plot.

If your application allows it, you could also adjust the `domain` argument for the inner axis in order to increase the accuracy.

I think you could also generate some rectangular border around the "magnified" solution. If it needs to be precise, it would need to be done manually using `\draw ... rectangle ...;`. An imprecise rectangle could be achieved using `\node[rectangle,draw=black,text width=...,pin=.....]`.

Comment: Thanks. It's a very nice solution. May I ask whether it is possible to let the `pin` line end a little bit closer to the "magnified" solution's axis?

Comment: The pin line is always near some point of the boundary. To adjust its location, we can either modify the boundary (for example using `xlabel style={overlay}`) or we can change the angle in which the pin points to its node (like `pin=180:...`).

Comment: How can I remove the white frame around the axis (not the label) of smaller plot?

Comment: The white fill color is due to the definition of `every pin`. If you want to keep the white color inside of the rectangle and get rid of the outer space, you should ask a separate question as this requires more bounding box control.