# How can I place an inset inside a pgfplots axis using the parent axis coordinates?

Tags: pgfplots

I'd like to place an inset axis inside a parent axis with `pgplots`. The position, width and height of the inset axis should be specified using the data coordinates of the parent axis. This is what I got so far:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[width=\textwidth,name=mainplot] 
    \addplot {x};
    \coordinate (insetSW) at (axis cs:-4,2); % south west corner of inset
    \coordinate (insetNE) at (axis cs:-2,4); % north east corner of inset
  \end{axis} 
  \begin{axis}[at={(insetSW)},anchor=south west,name=inset] 
    \addplot {x};
  \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

The south west corner of the inset is at the correct position. How can I calculate the width and height of the inset, so that its north east corner is at `insetNE`?

Or, is it possible to specify the axis dimensions by providing two coordinates to `\begin{axis}[..]`?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve a spy plot? See [plot within a plot: zoom into a plot so that the magnified part is framed by axis with ticks and tick labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42585/plot-within-a-plot-zoom-into-a-plot-so-that-the-magnified-part-is-framed-by-axi) and [How to add axes in a magnified part of a graph using spy?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61567/how-to-add-axes-in-a-magnified-part-of-a-graph-using-spy).

Comment: @PierPaolo A spy plot, yes..but without using `\spy`. The questions you referenced look very interesting, however, as far as I can see, they don't address the problem of specifying width and height of the inset in parent axis coordinates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is to cacluate width and height by the given coordinates inside a `let` statement. Then [save the result of the calculation to a macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27836/saving-computed-number-registers-for-access-outside-body-of-let-operation) and use this macro when creating the inset axis. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}  
  \pgfkeys{/tikz/savenumber/.code 2 args={\global\edef#1{#2}}}
  \begin{axis}[width=200pt,name=mainplot,xtick={-4,0},ytick={2,6},grid] 
    \addplot {x};
    \coordinate (insetSW) at (axis cs:-4,2); % south west corner of inset
    \coordinate (insetNE) at (axis cs:0,6); % north east corner of inset
    \path
      let
        \p1 = (insetSW),
        \p2 = (insetNE),
        \n1 = {(\x2 - \x1)},
        \n2 = {(\y2 - \y1)}
      in    
      [savenumber={\insetwidth}{\n1},savenumber={\insetheight}{\n2}];
  \end{axis}
  \begin{axis}[
    at={(insetSW)}, anchor=south west, name=inset, width=\insetwidth,
    height=\insetheight, xticklabels={}, yticklabels={}, scale only axis]
    \addplot {x};
  \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

% DEBUG
inset width: \insetwidth,
inset height: \insetheight,
\end{document}
```

Which produces

[image: Screenshot of the ouput of the above code]

The inset has the desired position with the lower left corner at `(-4,2)` and the upper right corner at `(0,6)`. The tick labels of the inset axis have been removed to prevent a `width/height is too small...` error. The key `scale only axis` has to be provided to the inset axis, so that the axis exactly matches the desired dimensions.

Comments/alternative answers are very welcome!