# Plot magnification using sub-plot within a plot!

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, spy

How can I produce such kind of zooming shown in the figure? Here the selected portion is plotted again with new axis displaying more details than just magnifying the portion.
One solution is to generate separate axis in a node and plot the selected portion again like what is mentioned in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42591/24167. However, this method needs inputting the plot points again for the new axis which might not be straightforward and if the whole chunk of the data is copied and pasted the tikz file size may significantly increase when plotting the data point by point.

Using `tikz spy` the portion is magnified, line widths increase and no plot details added. I would like to re-plot the selection so I can get more waveform details in the magnified area.

Is there any code/package available with similar and easy usage as `tikz spy` to produce these kind of zooming?

[image]

**EDIT:**
MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\usetikzlibrary{spy,backgrounds}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}
\addplot [
color=blue,
solid,
forget plot
]
coordinates {(1,-0.483783330986617)(2,-0.0340145593918096)(3,-0.436539522180039)(4,0.209777110368882)(5,0.859135420044728)(6,0.85161903717295)(7,1.55934912950599)(8,0.784047156239403)(9,-0.0792693910524122)(10,1.51723070777856)(11,1.40411965889846)(12,0.698986700228326)(13,1.05260397767063)(14,1.29723031913342)(15,1.15137784963834)(16,1.27812037219483)(17,0.946578586782951)(18,0.958318150506974)(19,0.981535539332581)(20,0.593435037539142)(21,1.43239361416853)(22,0.811029077471436)(23,1.02029755131029)(24,0.333489727091801)(25,0.168378017112723)(26,0.479114471344012)(27,0.326271147058235)(28,0.812917677609558)(29,0.481674812959686)(30,0.357325779724704)(31,-0.536395105252668)(32,-0.445451666510484)(33,-0.0769251588562435)(34,-0.394692291260873)(35,0.165251968372529)(36,0.0939410842571161)(37,-0.76215521666867)(38,-0.261803650146044)(39,-0.129586204410865)(40,-0.62840840652669)(41,-0.168924127696477)(42,-0.446602448770101)(43,-0.83052384153562)(44,-0.600880793103123)(45,-0.899767313148666)(46,-1.15964786754054)(47,-0.856539763806029)(48,-0.981675541618192)(49,-1.12830507985998)(50,-0.25051644785583)(51,-0.837305455241527)(52,0.208696378227061)(53,-0.950733595562766)(54,-0.54704626678199)(55,-0.0724920603515025)(56,0.46042541141183)(57,-0.42925983026122)(58,-0.78070557085291)(59,-0.0525245718275866)(60,-0.807376579142401)(61,-0.291700808122719)(62,0.0256573658235369)(63,0.612635303598783)(64,0.691405814766423)(65,0.204095429463616)(66,0.681113889563989)(67,0.276337752630281)(68,0.758563305598775)(69,1.34455733980387)(70,0.719690442645654)(71,0.608754456948268)(72,0.593653952861215)(73,1.13702517285714)(74,1.43362358662853)(75,1.78827195551751)(76,0.989537985806528)(77,1.05338260108987)(78,0.745460649186608)(79,1.64373793892591)(80,0.959178756948547)(81,0.780594953512541)(82,1.81442687142266)(83,1.22612427626548)(84,1.14113602979919)(85,0.396258658838045)(86,0.907991743167006)(87,0.871026667132155)(88,0.148019385955106)(89,0.410703075736867)(90,0.250149774622082)(91,0.530242048517334)(92,-0.179895231545825)(93,0.560065131748798)(94,0.738725310101912)(95,-0.196652928509654)(96,-0.177805433820475)(97,-0.069106615796877)(98,0.114821666222169)(99,-0.24872880189583)(100,-0.38520267397054)

};
\coordinate (pt) at (axis cs:30,0.7);
\end{axis}


\node[pin=10:{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
    \begin{axis}[
      xmin=27,xmax=30,
      ymin=0.6,ymax=0.7,
      line join=round,
      enlargelimits,width = 4cm
    ]
\addplot [
color=blue,
solid,
forget plot
]
coordinates{
 (1,-0.483783330986617)(2,-0.0340145593918096)(3,-0.436539522180039)(4,0.209777110368882)(5,0.859135420044728)(6,0.85161903717295)(7,1.55934912950599)(8,0.784047156239403)(9,-0.0792693910524122)(10,1.51723070777856)(11,1.40411965889846)(12,0.698986700228326)(13,1.05260397767063)(14,1.29723031913342)(15,1.15137784963834)(16,1.27812037219483)(17,0.946578586782951)(18,0.958318150506974)(19,0.981535539332581)(20,0.593435037539142)(21,1.43239361416853)(22,0.811029077471436)(23,1.02029755131029)(24,0.333489727091801)(25,0.168378017112723)(26,0.479114471344012)(27,0.326271147058235)(28,0.812917677609558)(29,0.481674812959686)(30,0.357325779724704)(31,-0.536395105252668)(32,-0.445451666510484)(33,-0.0769251588562435)(34,-0.394692291260873)(35,0.165251968372529)(36,0.0939410842571161)(37,-0.76215521666867)(38,-0.261803650146044)(39,-0.129586204410865)(40,-0.62840840652669)(41,-0.168924127696477)(42,-0.446602448770101)(43,-0.83052384153562)(44,-0.600880793103123)(45,-0.899767313148666)(46,-1.15964786754054)(47,-0.856539763806029)(48,-0.981675541618192)(49,-1.12830507985998)(50,-0.25051644785583)(51,-0.837305455241527)(52,0.208696378227061)(53,-0.950733595562766)(54,-0.54704626678199)(55,-0.0724920603515025)(56,0.46042541141183)(57,-0.42925983026122)(58,-0.78070557085291)(59,-0.0525245718275866)(60,-0.807376579142401)(61,-0.291700808122719)(62,0.0256573658235369)(63,0.612635303598783)(64,0.691405814766423)(65,0.204095429463616)(66,0.681113889563989)(67,0.276337752630281)(68,0.758563305598775)(69,1.34455733980387)(70,0.719690442645654)(71,0.608754456948268)(72,0.593653952861215)(73,1.13702517285714)(74,1.43362358662853)(75,1.78827195551751)(76,0.989537985806528)(77,1.05338260108987)(78,0.745460649186608)(79,1.64373793892591)(80,0.959178756948547)(81,0.780594953512541)(82,1.81442687142266)(83,1.22612427626548)(84,1.14113602979919)(85,0.396258658838045)(86,0.907991743167006)(87,0.871026667132155)(88,0.148019385955106)(89,0.410703075736867)(90,0.250149774622082)(91,0.530242048517334)(92,-0.179895231545825)(93,0.560065131748798)(94,0.738725310101912)(95,-0.196652928509654)(96,-0.177805433820475)(97,-0.069106615796877)(98,0.114821666222169)(99,-0.24872880189583)(100,-0.38520267397054)
  };  
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}] at (pt) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The first way (using a second `axis` environment) is quite convenient, as long as you provide the data in a table or read it directly from a file. Could you provide an example of how you generate your plots?

Comment: Just added a MWE. What I would like to do is to make a similar command like `spy` so it can automatically zoom in to the portion of the data but using a new axis and using the point data I've already indicated for `plot coordinates`.

Comment: @M.Reza I don't think there's an existing command in `pgfplots` that lets you do this. but it would be nice to have it. Since you want to plot the coordinates and plot magnitude as well, you're basically looking for a sub-plot operation (not as your title suggests a magnification operation) and it makes sense if `pgfplots` provides it. In fact I cannot see how it can be produced without interacting with `pgfplots`.

Comment: @Mark Thanks, Yes in fact I am looking for a sub-plot which automatically redraw the selected portion just like `spy` (in 2D plots). I changed the title to accommodate your point

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that Pgfplots only allows to generate multiple axes which may overlap, just as you did for your example.

A way to simplify the syntax overhead could be to define some macro which re-generates the plot along with all its style options and the coordinates.

Note that even *if* pgfplots would offer some "sub-plot" operation, it would do the very same thing. This means that the pdf file size would be as large as in your attempt.

If you believe that pgfplots should offer such a feature, you can post a feature request on sourceforge. Personally, I am not fully sure if I understand thefeature scope, i.e. what it should do and what it should not do. So just in case you want to post a feature request, please elaborate on these details.