# pgfplots - Provide a detailed plot inside the main plot

Tags: pgfplots

I have a main plot and *inside* it I would like to add a smaller plot that offers a higher level of detail.

A rough illustration of the above is:

[image]

Notice that the smaller plot provides a more detailed evolution of the blue curve when the latter approaces the x-axis.

How can I do that using the `pgfplots` package?

Comment: Is zooming in a valid option? If so you can try the spy library of TikZ.

Comment: Related [plot within a plot: zoom into a plot so that the magnified part is framed by axis with ticks and tick labels](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42585), [Plot magnification using sub-plot within a plot!](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96987) (unanswered), [tikz spy library with pgfplots: opacity and grid](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14432)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure why the `spy` library isn't suitable, but you can achieve what you want by using

```
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\savebox{\mybox}{%
      <code for miniature figure>
}
```

and then `\usebox{\mybox}` at an appropriate place on the axis. Note that you can't use a `node` directly as `pgfplots` won't allow you to nest axis.

[image]

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\savebox{\mybox}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=25,
               ymin=0,ymax=1,
               grid=both,
               width=6cm,
               height=3cm]
               \addplot expression[domain=1:25,red,mark=none,very thick]{sin(deg(1/x))};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=25,
               ymin=0,ymax=1,
               grid=both]
               \addplot expression[domain=1:25]{sin(deg(1/x))};
               \draw (axis cs: 13,.4)node{\usebox{\mybox}};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: gee thanks @cmhughes!! As per the `spy` library, I got the idea (obviously wrong) from the examples and www.texample.com that the miniature would be located outside the main plot.

Comment: you can add the axis property `axis background/.style={fill=white}` so that the grid lines of the two plots do not mix.

Comment: Nice solution. However, I noticed that the second plot will always be inside the main plot area, which crops the xtick/ytick labels when I place it near the edge. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: @joaocandre I suppose you could move the ticks, or make them smaller, or just have a whole other subplot...

Comment: first of all let me admit that this is very nice work. However I have a question. Although i managed to implement this correctly and looks fine within LaTeX, when i try to export the image as a pdf using the externalize command, I get 2 discrete image-pdf's rather than a single pdf. Any ideas?